# Let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be two commutable diagonal endomorphisms. Then there is a basis consisting of eigenvectors of both $\phi$ and $\psi$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Since $\phi$ and $\psi$ commute, I can prove that for a basis for $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $\phi$, {$v_1, ..., v_n$}, then it must be that $\psi(v_i)$ is an eigenvector of $\phi$ for all $v_i$. Moreover, $\psi(v_i)$ and $v_i$ correspond to the same eigenvalue. From here, I'm not really sure to go though. A hint would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "diagonal"?

Comment: Instead fof eigenvectors, consider eigenspaces. You just shows that $\phi$-eigenspaces are $\psi$-invariant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\phi$ is diagonalisable, with distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ for example, $V$ decomposes as a direct sum
$$ V = V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_n$$
where $\phi$ acts on $V_i$ by the scalar $\lambda_i$. Now you need to show that $\psi$ respects this decomposition, i.e. $\psi(V_i) \subseteq V_i$ for each $i$: this happens because $\psi$ and $\phi$ commute.

Finally, use the fact that $\psi$ is diagonalisable to find a basis of $\psi$-eigenvectors for each $V_i$, and argue that these are all also eigenvectors of $\phi$.